# Find $\operatorname{lcm}(2n-1,2n+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm, least-common-multiple

I'm trying to find the formula for $\operatorname{lcm}(2n-1,2n+1)$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Here is my solution but I'm not sure about it.
We know that
$$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\frac{\lvert ab \lvert}{\gcd(a,b)}$$
Now if we substitute we have:
$$\operatorname{lcm}(2n-1,2n+1)=\frac{\lvert (2n-1)(2n+1) \lvert}{\gcd(2n-1,2n+1)}=\frac{\lvert (4n^2-1) \lvert}{\gcd(2n-1,2n+1)}$$
Now we compute $\gcd(2n-1,2n+1)$, We can notice that
$$2n+1=(2n-1)+2$$
Thus the 2 arguments are not divisible (unless $n=0$) hence $\gcd(2n-1,2n+1)=1$

We can conclude that
$$\operatorname{lcm}(2n-1,2n+1)=\lvert (4n^2-1) \lvert$$

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: $n=1$ would be another case where the bottom is divisible by the larger as the arguments become 1 and 3, just as a minor side point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{lcm}(2n-1,2n+1) = \frac{(2n-1)(2n+1)}{\gcd(2n-1,2n+1)}$$

Note that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a-b,b)$ if $a>b$, and $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,b-a)$ if $a<b$.

Since $2n+1 > 2n-1$:

$$\frac{(2n-1)(2n+1)}{\gcd(2n-1,2n+1 - (2n-1))} = \frac{(2n-1)(2n+1)}{\gcd(2n-1,2)} = (2n-1)(2n+1)$$

Comment: I approve your expression $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a-b,b)$ but I have the suspect that it's independent from the condition that a>b

Comment: @aibohphobia It is as long as you're defining $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(|a|,|b|)$ -- otherwise the resulting $\gcd$ may be negative (depending on definition / implementation / etc.). It's usually easier to keep the arguments positive if you can. See also the Euclidean algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm

Answer (score 5):

Your logic is totally correct except that the logic for the **gcd** can be better written as follows:

> $(2n - 1)$ and $(2n + 1)$ are consecutive odd integers and hence they are co-prime i.e. $\gcd(2n - 1, 2n + 1) = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your work is fine. A slightly different formulation of your study of the greatest common divisor would be to notice that the gcd of two numbers divides their difference, which is $2$. Hence, the gcd is either $1$ or $2$, and the fact that they are both odd implies that it's $1$.